# How to create the vsmdi/testrunconfig file when importing a Visual Studio test project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, testrunconfig

When I add an existing test project, my solution lacks the vsdmi and the testrunconfig files. How to create it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2010 just go to **Test** → **Create New Test List...**

It will automatically add the `vsdmi` file and put it into the correct location, no need to add a solution item manually.

Comment: Would you mind updating for VS 2015? That menu now just has an option to select an existing .testrunconfig file, as far as I can see.

Comment: @willmuphyscode, I don't have a good understanding of what's a recommended way to do this in VS2015 is, but I think they got rid of *.vsmdi files and replaced it with something called Playlists. I would try to understand why and what you actually need to do here and see how it's done in VS2015 because the answer above might not be the right solution using the newer tools.

Answer (score 21):

The solution to this is a little tricky. You have to add a "New Item" to your solution, not your test project. In the "Add New Item" dialog, you can pick the "Test Run Configuration" category and then create the configuration file manually. This will also generate a vsdmi file.

Hope this helps.