# Cannot find any coverage data (ASP.NET MVC2)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-2

I am having some issues with getting Code Coverage working with an out-of-the-box ASP.NET MVC2 Web App

VS2010 Ultimate, File > New Project > ASP.NET MVC 2 Web Application > Yes, Create unit test project with Visual Studio Unit Test.  I then Rebuild All, Run All Unit Tests, Go to Code Coverage and get the following message:

> Cannot find any coverage data (.coverage or .coveragexml) files.  Check test run details for possible errors.

All the unit tests passed.  (And I haven't touched a line of code yet)

I did find the following on the web:
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=615377
which says to do the following:

> Test -> Edit Test Settings -> Local
>   In the test settings dialog, click
>   "Data and Diagnostics"   Ensure "Code
>   Coverage" are checked, and
>   double-click on it Check of the dll's
>   you want code coverage enabled for.

But, when I go to Test > Edit Test Seetings, all I see is the grayed out menu item stating "No Test Settings Available".

Any ideas?

Edit: slowly gaining traction. See: [How to create the vsmdi/testrunconfig file when importing a Visual Studio test project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155743/how-to-create-the-vsmdi-testrunconfig-file-when-importing-a-visual-studio-test-pr)

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same problem occur when I added a test project from another source (ie added to, but not created in the current solution).  When doing this, local.testsettings, Solution.vsmdi, and TraceAndTestImpact.testsettings are NOT created inside your solution.

This fix is really quite simple, though.  Simply right click on your solution and click Add -> New item.  A new window will appear.  On the left-hand side under General and Performance should be Test Settings.  This should let you add a .testsettings file that you can now edit.

More information can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256991%28v=vs.100%29.aspx